# Once after installation of ubuntu restarting is taking long time

Tags: 14.04

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04. once after installation it asked for restarting. I restarted my laptop. Restarting was happening for an hour. So I pressed power button and switched off the laptop.After that it started normally.
My question is as I interrupted restarting will it affect in future???

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing you can do once a shutdown/restart has been initiated except to wait like you did. When the system has been unresponsive for a unreasonable amount of time a power reset is your only option. If something went terribly wrong it will certainly make itself known when you start the system back up.